# Better way to display excessive data in table cell iOS

Tags: interaction-design, mobile, design-patterns, tables, mobile-application

I am displaying data retrieved from server in `UITableView.` Each cell has to display more than 10 fields as shown in figure. Its looking very ugly if I just simply put up the fields in cell. I have checked mobile patterns but they does n't contain large data example. Please tell me a better way to display excessive data - or have anyone got an idea for some alternate...? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What are **two** Logout buttons doing in the bottom bar?

Comment: These are just dummy icons. They are not for logout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really understand about this data, but tried to put my recommendations in the mockup (see it below):

- Group similar information
- Put focus on main information
- Increase readability by using light colors
- Don't show irrelevant information. E.g. if there's no pending sell, don't show it.

[image: Recommendation]

Comment: Wow... this is so awesome beyond my imagination... Thank you so much for such a superb idea :) Can you tell me the name of the tool you used to draw this mockup? Thanks :)

Comment: Simple, Adobe Photoshop